# Calculating the Galois group of a covering map

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Suppose $C$ is an algebraic curve and $\phi:C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ is a covering map of the complex projective line ramified at $\{0,1,\infty\}$ only. Suppose $\phi':C'\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1-\{0,1,\infty\}$ is obtained from $\phi$ by restricting the domain away from the cusps. Then we can speak of the Galois group of the covering map $\phi'$. Conversely, since the fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^1-\{0,1,\infty\}$ is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, the free group of two generators, any quotient of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to some covering map.

My question is: how can we give explicit construction for this bijection. That is, given a algebraic curve and a covering map, how do we determine its Galois group, and conversely, given a Galois group, how do we find such a covering map.

For example, when we take the curve to be the $n^{th}$ Fermat curve $x^n+y^n=z^n$, then the Galois group is just $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, the abelianization of the free group modulo $n$. Could someone explain to me how we can go back and forth between covering maps and Galois group using this example?

Comment: Be careful of the phrase `Galois group of the covering map $\phi'$'. Not all such coverings are Galois and the associated Galois group will in general only detect a further cover of $C'$.

Comment: Are you still seeking an answer for this question? There are few parts should be modified -- for example, the fundamental group of thrice-punctured projective line is not the free group of rank 2. You should take the profinite completion, since you are working on algebraic curves.

Comment: Anyway, let me focus on the last part of your question. You can write down the covering map explicitly, namely $(x,y)\mapsto x^n$. Here, I am using the equation $x^n+y^n=1$ rather than $x^n+y^n=z^n$. After writing down the explicit map, you can immediately see why this covering has $\mathbb{Z}/n\times\mathbb{Z}/n$ as its Galois group. Also, I believe that you would derive the other direction when you figure out what the quotient map $\pi_1(\mathbf{P}^1-3\mathrm{pt})\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/n\times\mathbb{Z}/n$ is.

Comment: The general correspondence which you are looking for is quite hard. It depends on your desired degree of explicitness. But I believe, in any degree, it is quite hard in both directions, and there is no general way for the explicit constructions.